# Trailing whitespace after tag with class with slim

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I'm trying to add trailing whitespace in a slim template after a font-awesome icon.

The template looks like this:

```
=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i.icon-pencil
  | edit
```

I want to add whitespace after the  tag (or before the text), so I tried the following combinations:

```
=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i>.icon-pencil
  | edit


=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i.icon-pencil>
  | edit


=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i<.icon-pencil
  | edit


=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i.icon-pencil<
  | edit


=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i.icon-pencil
  < edit
```

and many more...

Maybe I'm just too stupid to understand the docs. The only solution I found working (but it looks super unelegant) was:

```
=link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i.icon-pencil
  '
  | edit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
|  edit (two spaces)

From the docs:
"If the text starts on the same line, the left margin is set at the indent of the pipe + one space. Any additional spaces will be copied over."

Answer (score 0):

I came here from google search, and slim template 4.0.1 works as expected.

There is correct answer in the question:

```
= link_to edit_path(the_object) do
  i.icon-pencil>
  | edit
```

will produce trailing space after `<i>` tag

```
<a href="http://a.lv"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> edit</a>
```